# tricky select query, need assistance

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I have a table named **psroleuser**, which haves coulmns **rolename, roleuser.**

For each rolename, there are a set of roleuser, for eg rolename A can have 20 roleusers, rolename B can have 30 roleusers.

Now, I want to select all roles i.e rolenames which haves 10 roleusre or less.

How to do it.? I understnad this is very elementry in database, but so am I..plus can anyone suggest good oracle,sql reads to start with.

Thank you.

Comment: what are the columns in those tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share the columns in those tables, and I'm not directly familiar with PeopleSoft, but it sounds like there's also a User table (or similar), and the roleuser table maps those user records to rolename records. If that's true, the table will have columns with names something like `RoleID` and `UserID`. Using those columns as examples, you'll end up with something like this:

```
SELECT RoleID
FROM RoleUser
GROUP BY RoleID
HAVING COUNT(UserID) <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rolename
  FROM psroleuser
 GROUP BY rolename
 HAVING COUNT(1) <= 10;
```